# How do i sum four columns after a count in sql

Tags: php

```
MariaDB [blog]> SELECT count(main_dish),count(soup_stew),count(meat_fish),count(other) FROM foodlist;
```

Output :

```
+------------------+------------------+------------------+--------------+
| count(main_dish) | count(soup_stew) | count(meat_fish) | count(other) |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+--------------+
|                3 |                3 |                3 |            3 |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+--------------+
```

Please i want to add them in other to get 12,can someone help me out

Comment: SELECT (SUM(COUNT(main_dish))+SUM(COUNT(soup_stew))+...)) AS Total FROM  your_table

Comment: Please upvote my answer or accept as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT (count(main_dish)+count(soup_stew)+count(meat_fish)+count(other)) as total FROM foodlist;
```

Comment: Thanks very much....it worked

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(main_dish),
COUNT(soup_stew),
COUNT(meat_fish),
COUNT(other),
COUNT(main_dish) + COUNT(soup_stew) + COUNT(meat_fish) + COUNT(other) AS 'total' FROM foodlist;
```

Comment: sure about the `'`?

Comment: safer to do it that way in case you wanted a column name like 'Total (dishes)'

Comment: but it should be backticks `\``, shouldn't it?

Comment: for string literals, stick with `'`